# Skype just loaded after booting PC

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, login, skype

This might be a stupid question but I'm quite concerned, I have just booted my PC and Skype loaded with me signed in.

I don't use Skype, and if I did sign up for an account, it was a very long time ago. 
Skype has never been logged in or even used on this machine, and no friends or family members also use this PC.

Does anybody know if Windows has had a update which enables this?

I'm on Windows 10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop Skype from starting automatically when booting Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1288235/how-to-stop-skype-from-starting-automatically-when-booting-windows-10)

Comment: no, as skype has never loaded before, nor have i used it on this machine, no family members use this machine

Comment: Microsoft most likely updated Skype through a windows update which is known to make it start on system start.

Comment: Ok thanks, i just grilled my daughter asking has she been on the pc."well skype dont load it's self"....
i think i might owe her an apology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too had Skype just "appear" this morning when turning on the machine, and couldn't getting any success in removing it via the usual methods - Programs and Features, Remove from Startup within Task Manager, Find a Windows Service relating to it to stop, etc.

What I have found that has worked so far is:

1. Going into Windows 10 Settings (Start -> Settings 'icon')
2. Select 'Apps'
3. Scroll through the list of apps until you find the 'Skype' entry. For me, I saw the install date (on the right hand side) as yesterday's date, so it was clearly a recent addition (and not one I authorised, or knew anything about I might add!)
4. Click on the Skype app, 'Advanced Options' appear just under the 'Skype' name
5. An 'Advanced Options' will appear just under the 'Skype' name, click on it
6. Click on the 'Terminate' button
7. Click on the 'Uninstall' button

As I said, this worked for me this morning, but I have seen reports of people stating the 'Uninstall' button within the 'Advanced Options' (Step 7 above) is greyed out for them, but still worth a try!