# Windows 10: Skype on startup - how to disable

Tags: windows-10, skype, skype-for-windows-10

Skype has been changed from a stand alone application to a microsoft store application which changes how it used to be managed for windows 10.

I always had skype disabled on startup for a long long time now as I can't really use skype myself due to being deaf.

I instead use a different solution if I want to call someone (dedicated interpreter service such as Purple VRS). I use yet another solution instead of skype if I want to video chat which is better than skype at any rate.

I only recently noticed that most methods on search yield results for older versions of skype and don't provide useful answer.

All I can do right now is to kill the process but I want to disable/block it from starting up each time I boot up my PC.

Worse yet it doesn't allow me to uninstall it like at all... All it does is redirection me to microsoft store application and give me option to "share".

Comment: See if it is on the startup tab in msconfig, if it is un tick it.

Comment: That doesn't work as it ask you to instead use task manager and provide you a link to it. Msconfig has been like that for a while now.

Comment: So did you try to disable it in task manager?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop Skype from starting automatically when booting Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1288235/how-to-stop-skype-from-starting-automatically-when-booting-windows-10)

Comment: Nothing shows up in task manager's startup list for skype.

Comment: @Run5k That question is from a year ago and the application itself no longer has a tool in the first answer.

Comment: We are always glad to help, but the age of the question is irrelevant when it is the *exact* same problem. Also, the first (and only) answer has more than one solution listed.

Comment: The age of the answer is such that it no longer is possible to use it. For example, App and feature uninstall button? Not there. Also skype is now a microsoft store application not a stand alone application.

Comment: @Vyndicu `Apps & features` absolutely exists if you search for it within the Settings UWP application.  I have confirmed this is the case on 1803 and 1809 VMs.  This is absolutely a duplicate of the existing question.  "Skype is now a Microsoft store application, not a stand-alone application" - This is false.  Skype no matter which version (UWP or Desktop) is an optional application that can be uninstalled.

Comment: *"Also skype is now a microsoft store application not a stand alone application."*  Yes, I know.  That is why that answer references both the stand-alone Skype installer version (utilizing the **Tools** > **Options** method) as well as the **Skype UWP** version, which you colloquially referred to as a Microsoft Store application. And at the risk of asking an obvious question, did you actually *select* **Skype** on the `Apps & features` list utilizing a left-click?  That should make the `Uninstall` button appear. If Skype is running, first choose `Advanced options` and then `Terminate` the app.

Comment: Yesterday, I saw a new icon on the task bar. I didn't recall installing a new application at all which made it likely that it was installed along a microsoft patch. When I hover over to see which program it was and was surprised to see it was skype since I long time ago deleted it from my PC. Then I navigated to app & feature and search for skype nothing showed up. Same for msconfig/task manager startup. Finally the only option I saw was to terminate process skype. I reinstall skype, now it did showed up for app & feature which is odd since I clearly remember search for it there yesterday.

Comment: *"edit to add info to clarify that the other question answer no longer works"*  Yes, [it does](https://superuser.com/questions/1288235/how-to-stop-skype-from-starting-automatically-when-booting-windows-10/1290116#1290116).  More importantly, it is the **exact** same question, so the duplicate label is valid.