# How to automatically start Skype from MS Store?

Tags: windows-10, skype

Skype Version: 8.56.0.102
App Version: 14.56.102.0
Windows 10 fully up-to-date.

There is no auto start flag under settings - general, there's no skype entry in autostart section in Task Manager, so how do you make it automatically start with Windows?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using this version and not the desktop one? In desktop Skype I see "Automatically start Skype" in General. Add a screenshot of yours.

Comment: If you are actually logged into Skype, it should already be starting automatically unless you went out of your way to configure to *not* start in that manner.  If anything, many people within the Super User realm have encountered [the exact opposite problem](https://superuser.com/questions/1288235/how-to-stop-skype-from-starting-automatically-when-booting-windows-10).

Comment: I'm using the UWP App because it's more convenient to me.

Comment: "If you close your computer without signing out of the Skype UWP application, then on next computer boot, Skype will auto run in the background. To maximize Skype UWP you will just need to click on the application icon." I hope I'll still get incoming calls when the app is not maximized. Thanks

Comment: That's the answer to your question right there. UWP apps remain in the state they were when the OS was shut down. The statement you quoted clearly states the app is running if it was open when the system was shut off. If the app is running it will receive calls. The shortcut only maximizes the app in this state. Maximize is not the same thing as start.