# (Windows 10) How can I disable Skype popping up on startup?

Tags: windows-10, skype

Whenever I startup my Windows 10 laptop and then log in, the second the home screen appears, Skype starts up, covering up the home screen completely.

I need to keep on closing the Skype window to get that thing off of my screen.  It's **extremely** annoying.

***How can I disable this?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Task Manager and navigate to the 'Start-up' tab. Find Skype in the list of applications, right-click it and select 'Disable'. This will prevent Skype from loading on start-up.

Comment: We always appreciate contributions from the Super User community, but please do a bit more research before you answer.  We have a canonical Q&A that has more than 200,000 views regarding this exact same question, and the author should have been guided *there,* instead:  [How to stop Skype from starting automatically when booting Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1288235/how-to-stop-skype-from-starting-automatically-when-booting-windows-10)  Thanks for your understanding.